# how to fix search form with only div no form

Tags: bootstrap-4

hellow i want to use this search form and it wont work for me pleas help

```html
<form name="search" onSubmit="if(document.search.search.value==''){return false;}" method="get" action="/search.php">
<div class="input-group"> <input type="text" name="search" class="input-sm form-control input-s-sm" placeholder="<?php echo $search_text; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="change" value="1"> <button class="searchbut"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

wont to put it hear

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md scrolling-navbar">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="pl-0 pr-0 ml-1 mt-0 resmt-1" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExample"><i class="fa fa-bars box-icon"></i></a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo_mtube.jpg" alt="logo"/>
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler blue-gradient" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <div class="input-group md-form form-sm form-2 pl-0">
                            <input class="form-control my-0 py-1 red-border" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                            <span class="input-group-addon indigo white-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search text-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </div>
```

Comment: any one can help me pleas

Comment: what exactly is your issue?

Comment: i need to make this form work